# Cannot set property 'className' of null for and id within an id

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting the error `Cannot set property 'className' of null` when trying to set the class name in JS. My JS is like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get('/price',function(data) {
      document.title = `($${data.price}) The Price`;
      document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = `$${data.change}`;
      document.getElementById("p4").className = "increase";
      document.getElementById("p5").className = "triangle-down";
  });
}, 30000);
```

The line in the HTML is:

```
<h1 class="decrease" id="p4">$5<i class="triangle-up" id="p5"></i></h1>
```

I always get the same error. However if I comment out the line below it works:

```
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = `$${data.change}`;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: Why `document.getElementById("p4").className = "increase"` instead of `$("#p4").addClass("increase")`?

Comment: You are most likely running the JavaScript before the DOM has finished loading. Make sure that either you place your code at the bottom of the HTML or that you wrap it in a "DOMContentLoaded" event callback.

Comment: When do you call your javascript function? Cannot set property 'className' of null means that document.getElementById("p4") returns null, or in other words, that there is no element with the id "p4" in your DOM. This might happen because $.get() is asynchronus function and gets called before the DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: Guys, this code is in a setInterval, it runs after 30 _seconds_...

Comment: @JeremyThille That does not guarantee that the DOM is fully loaded by then. It should, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: A simple test would be to add `console.log(document.getElementById("p4"));` to the first line of code in the `$.get()` function and see what it is.

Comment: I think we don't need the DOM to be fully loaded, with images and stuff. We need the HTML markup to be present, and unless there are 800 billion lines and the user has a 56k connection, it _will_ be present long before 30 seconds.

Comment: @JeremyThille `DOMContentLoaded` fires when the DOM has been built and is in memory. `load` waits for all resources to have completed being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the inside of your h1 tag:

```
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = `$${data.change}`;
```

what is the result of:

```
`$${data.change}`
```

make sure that the above variable retuns the following html: (edit: i mean the following format)

```
<h1 class="decrease" id="p4">$5<i class="triangle-up" id="p5"></i></h1>
```

Comment: p4 is not the problem, p5 is, and since p5 is inside p4, it is lost after .innerHTML i changed, isn't that correct  ?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation inside the code

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get('/price',function(data) {
      document.title = `($${data.price}) The Price`;
      // Step by step:    
      // You change innerHTML of id=p4, but your new html might not 
      // contents the <i class="triangle-up" id="p5"></i>
      document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = `$${data.change}`;

      // you changing class of p4 this is ok
      document.getElementById("p4").className = "increase"

      // you are trying to change class of p5, but two lines above you
      // replaced it by $${data.change} that probably don't contains 
      // div with id=p5 and it looks like there is no more div id=p5 on the page
      // that also explains why everything is ok if you comment this line
      document.getElementById("p5").className = "triangle-down"
  });
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Can try:

```
document.getElementById("p4").classList.remove('decrease');
document.getElementById("p4").classList.add('increase');
document.getElementById("p5").classList.remove('triangle-up');
document.getElementById("p5").classList.add('triangle-down');
```

Answer (score -2):

Could you possibly have missing semi-colons ';' at the end of the two className assignments?

Comment: that was a typo. sorry